# Angular dropdown with a button not getting data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, click

im new to angular and was struck linking dropdown selected to ng-click button

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <select name="cars" ng-model="dropdown_data">
      <option>email</option>
      <option>phone</option>
      <option>username</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <button type="button" class=" " data-ng-click="search_{{dropdown_data}}()">Search</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    var ng = angular.module('myApp', []);
    ng.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.search_phone = function() {
        alert("phone")
      }
      $scope.search_email = function() {
        alert("email")
      }
    }) 
  </script>
```

this seems to be fairly simple but im not sure what im doing wrong...Im not able to show alerts depending on selected dropdown

Plunker link http://plnkr.co/edit/Iicm9tvfizXxNl3MwtZI?p=preview

any help is much appriciated...thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is this `data-ng-click="search_{{dropdown_data}}()"`. Better to pass a value to the function like this:

```
<button type="button" data-ng-click="search(dropdown_data)">Search</button>

$scope.search = function(type) {
    alert(type)
}
```

also dont forget ng-app and ng-controller.

see [the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V70dEUBFFyBKi9kmgRei?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for the reply..........can you plz edit the punker..which could be much helpfull....  :)

Comment: i did. see my answer

Answer (score 1):

There were few things that you needed in the plunkr.

Firstly you need to define on the HTML that it is in fact an Angular Application (via the ngApp attribute).
Secondly you need to define a controller for your view (via the ngController attribute).

Once you have those things in place, you need to understand what this would do

```
ng-click="search_{{dropdown_data}}()"
```

If you think about how ng-click works, it registers a function on click. This happens on the `compile` phase of a directive ([as you can see on its sourcecode](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L55)).

This means that when the directive compiles, it will register the function with the name `search_{{dropdown_data}}` and even though the `dropdown_data` will be interpolated later on when its value changes, the originally bound function won't update.

However if you had dropdown_data as an attribute or as a key to a map of functions that will work. Here an example of how you may do that:

```
$scope.search = {
    phone: function() {
    alert("phone")
  },
  email: function() {
    alert("email")
  }
  };
```

and on the button: `data-ng-click="search[dropdown_data]()"`

Here a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/u4vJj2a0r1a95w64crHM?p=preview

Comment: adding a seperate function for every option is not that good. better use one search function that gets a value. see my answer and http://plnkr.co/edit/V70dEUBFFyBKi9kmgRei?p=preview

Comment: it depends on the use case. You may want to provide completely different implementations based on that parameter. 
I did specify that " if you had dropdown_data as an attribute or as a key to a map of functions that will work".

Comment: yes, but better call them from the search function. so there can be shared code and you won't ever have any naming issues (e.g. an option can have a space or special characters -> "email address" instead of "email"). just want to point out to keep future changes, maintenance and extensions in mind ;)

Comment: Sure, but it depends on the use case. In this case the question seemed to indicate that the intent was to call 2 different functions depending on the value of the select box. The best way to do that is to use a map of functions and a key to them.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new in angular but have used same functionality without search button direct given anchor link try this if you need,

```
 <div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="setContent">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            Subject
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li ng-repeat="a in subjects"><a href="#">{{a}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);    
app.controller('setContent', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.subjects = ['Math', 'Physics', 'Chemistry', 'Hindi', 'English'];
  });
});
```